# Converging Series of Necessary Condition

Tags: sequences-and-series

If the following sum converges for a positive function $f(n)<1$:

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln(1+f(n))
$$

Then can it be said that the following sum converges?

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(n)
$$

Comment: Yes because $ \ln(1+f(n))\sim f(n)$

Comment: "a positive function $f(n)<1$" So you mean, $0<f(n)<1$ for all $n$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose

$$0<f(n)<1\quad \forall\ n\in\mathbb{N},\quad \text{and}\quad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln(1+f(n))\quad \text{converges.}
$$

Then $f(n)\to 0^+\ $ as $\ n\to\infty,\ $ otherwise convergence wouldn't happen.

But as $x\to 0^+,\ \ln(1+x)\ $ and $\ x\ $ are relatively close to each other. This can be seen by looking at the [Maclaurin expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Natural_logarithm) of $\ \ln(1+x):$

$$\ln(1+x) = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} - \ldots \implies \lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{\ln(1+x)}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0^+} \left(1 - \frac{x}{2} + \frac{x^3}{3} - \ldots\right) = 1.$$

Now replace $\ x\ $ in the above working with $\ f(n):$

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\ln(1+f(n))}{f(n)} = 1.\qquad (1)$$

Therefore by the [Limit Comparison Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test), which says that due to $\ (1),\ $ either both series converge or both diverge; since $\ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ln(1+f(n))\ $ converges by assumption, $\ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\ f(n))\ $ must also converge.

Comment: How can the series converge to $0$ if every term in the series is positive?

Comment: Thanks, this also helped me answer my next question.